# Form reports mixes entry on multilanguage form

Tags: sitecore-forms, multilingual

We have a multilanguage forms in Spanish and Portuguese, we noticed that the form reports do not segregate responses per language so the CSV is filled with a mixture of Spanish and Portuguese entries. Are there alternatives to filter reports based on the language? Or are there known custom implementations that we could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of Sitecore you use? For sitecore 9 it might be you can do this by making sure the contact entity reference parameter is different based on form's language i.e. when you are creating a contact:

> Contact contact = new Contact(new ContactIdentifier("TestForm" +
> Sitecore.Context.Language, model.Email, ContactIdentifierType.Known);

Then the Source parameter will be different in your .csv based on what language is the form filled in and you can filter.